# Why can't I select this input field using this regex filter in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So I'm using [padolsey's regex filter](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) to try and select dynamically generated nested form fields.  Why do I keep getting an empty value for *test* in the selector code below?

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^s+|s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}

//selector code
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var test = $('input:regex(id, agreement_activities_attributes_\d*_id)');
    console.log(test);
});
```

**html code that contains input field I'm trying to select**

```
<input id="agreement_activities_attributes_0_id" name="agreement[activities_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="28" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the code.

```
.replace(/^s+|s+$/g,'')
```

should be

```
.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')
```

Then it should work.

The replacement removes any surrounding whitespace (trims the string). The space you used in the selector (`:regex(id, agreement_activities_attributes_\d*_id)`) would be included in the match pattern, and thus only match elements with an id that started with space.

Comment: Thanks, along with your suggestion, I also had to add one more backlash in my code as follows:  ```var test = $('input:regex(id, agreement_activities_attributes_\\d*_id)');```